# Can dishwasher lines be routed behind range?

Tags: kitchens, dishwasher

My kitchen set up goes from left to right: Cabinets, range, 18" dishwasher, sink, more cabinets. We would really like to upgrade to a full size dishwasher. I want to hack into the cabinets to do this.

The cabinets immediately to the right of the sink are not the right size, would take some work. The cabinet to the left of the range is perfectly sized interestingly. There seems to be a gap behind the range that could accommodate the dishwasher lines, but is that a stupid idea? I assume the oven is insulated since its not catching wood/drywall on fire.

Comment: I can't think of any resson why not, as long as the wall behind the range retains (or is repaired to) its required fire-blocking rating...?

Comment: @keshlam Can you cite the code that requires fire-rated drywall or other overtly fire-resistant wall materials around a kitchen range?

Comment: No, I can't cite code, but I can attest that in my area at least there's a requirement for 5/8 inch thick wallboard behind a freestanding range. (I had to do a bit of repair there when swapping outa failing range for a new one). Hence my phrasing: maintain whatever rating is required.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty safe assumption that the range is insulated. Otherwise it would not only pose a fire hazard to your walls and/or cabinetry, but would melt the insulation on its own wires. If it weren't insulated, it would also potentially melt linoleum flooring.

For extra safety, you could run braided metal hose, but I'd mainly consider that because it would be safer against abrasion.